# Вывод списка счетов с остатками

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли как-то ускорить следующий запрос?

Есть таблица счетов и таблица движений между счетами:

[image: Структура таблиц]

(Кому интересно поэкспериментировать - в html-комментарии убран скрипт создания таблиц, слишком длинный, чтобы выводить его в текст вопроса)

Я получаю список счетов и считаю два числа:

- сумму всех переводов с текущего счета на какой-то другой ("дебет" счёта)
- сумму всех переводов на текущий счет с других ("кредит" счёта)

Соответственно остатки на счетах — это разница между кредитом и дебетом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой запрос:

```
SELECT
  a.Id
, a.Title
, a.IsActive
, a.IsCorrespondent
, a.CurrencyId
--, (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0) FROM dbo.Transactions t2 WHERE a.Id = t2.DestinationId) credit
--, (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0) FROM dbo.Transactions t1 WHERE a.Id = t1.SourceId) debet
, ((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0) FROM dbo.Transactions t2 WHERE a.Id = t2.DestinationId) - (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0) FROM dbo.Transactions t1 WHERE a.Id = t1.SourceId)) Rest


FROM dbo.Accounts a
WHERE 1 = 1
AND a.IsCorrespondent = 0
```

Текущий план выполнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то ускорить такой запрос?

Я сам на текущий момент вижу только одно направление: заменить два скана таблицы транзакций на один, но пока не соображу как менять знак для величины перевода.

И, может у кого есть идеи получше?

ЗЫ Варианты типа такого:

```
, (
    SELECT
        SUM(case when a.id = sourceId then - Amount else Amount end )
    FROM dbo.Transactions WHERE a.Id = SourceId OR a.Id = DestinationId
  ) Rest
```

Выдают ошибку:

> Msg 8124, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 Multiple columns are specified in
>   an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an
>   expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that
>   outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Comment: менять знак в смысле, `sum(amount * (case when a.id = sourceId then -1 else 1 end))` ?

Comment: @teran Ага, только так сделать не даст: Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Comment: переборщил. `sum( ... then -avalue else avalue ... )`

Comment: @teran Нет, та же самая ошибка выдаётся.

Comment: а вычисляемый столбец с этим кейсом в таблицу, или вьюшку? или вернее cte/подзапрос вместо вьюшки

Comment: я так понимаю, что это будет работать, если изначально сделать джойн аккаунтов на транзакции, без подзапроса с суммой, а так да, в аггрегате подзапроса не получится использовать таблицу внешнего запроса

Comment: вопрос правда,будет ли один скан по общему условию эффективнее чем текущие два.